# Is consumer group isolated for every event hub?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

#### Situation:

- I've two **event hubs** in a single **event hub namespace**.
- For each **event hub**, I've created separate **consumer group** with the same name.
- I'm consuming events from those two event hubs in **parallel**.
- For some reason, events from second **event hub** are not processed.
- If I change name for **consumer groups**, so they differ, events are processed as expected.

#### Conclusion:

It looks like consumer groups are somehow shared between **event hubs** (topics).

This behavior is different from Kafka. Can anyone explain what happens there?

Answer (score 0):

A consumer group belongs to a specific Event Hub resource and does not exist as an independent entity.

> For each event hub, I've created separate consumer group with the same name.

These are independent and do not have any connection to each other, despite having the same name.  From the Event Hubs point of view, they are identified as "EH1\MyGroup" and "EH2\MyGroup".

> - I'm consuming events from those two event hubs in parallel.
> - For some reason, events from second event hub are not processed.
> - If I change name for consumer groups, so they differ, events are processed as expected.

There is not enough context in these statements to understand how you are reading events nor what the expected behavior should be.  I'd suggest letting us know which SDK package and version you're using and including a code snippet that demonstrates how you're reading.